# How to enforce a specific order for the windows opened by diffsplit?

Tags: vimscript, vimdiff

Calling `diffsplit {filename}` opens the new file at the top and the current file at the bottom. Similarly, the vertical version opens the new file on the left and the current file on the right.

Is it possible to change this behavior such that the windows are always opened in the exact opposite order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `:h 'splitbelow'`
- `:h 'splitright'`

If you add

```
set splitbelow splitright
```

To your vimrc, it would be the opposite to default behavior.
Note, it would affect all your splits, not only diffsplit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works on `diffsplit` but moves the cursor to the new file. Any ideas about how I can keep the cursor on the current file? Additionally, do you know how I can extend this to also work with vim-fugitive, e.g., `Gvdiffsplit`? I was under the impression that vim-fugitive uses `diffsplit`, and this would automatically apply.

Comment: Check fugitive help..., `:Gdiffsplit!` -- retain focus on the current window.